# Looking for Esek Hashchita

Tags: jewish-books, slaughter-shochet-shecht

Where can one acquire the Sefer 'Esek Hashchita' by Rabbi Dovid SHAFFIER?
Either pdf or hard copy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it here: https://www.blurb.com/b/6849444-esek-hashechita

The one I got is missing something between pages 14 and 15. I wrote to the author to get the missing text but never received a response.